# How to hide "Comments are disabled"

Tags: comments

is it possible to hide the string: "Comments are disabled" from everywhere?

I mean also from posts list, and post page :)

Thanks :)

EDIT:

sorry, the theme is Journal Cruch by Site5.com

However I resolved using

```
if (comments_open())
    comments_popup_link();
```

where the comments are displayed, but I don't like too much this solution :)

Comment: I guess you can add this string in nearly every thinkable way, so: no.... unless you delete everything per hand.

Comment: To which theme are you referring? I don't have that text any longer with twenty ten in trunk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Popup link takes five parameters.

```
comments_popup_link('No Comments','One Comment','Many Comments','CSSclass','Comments Disabled');
```

So you are on to the correct solution. Now just change the above strings to whatever you want them to be for each # of comments. Finally change 'Comments Disabled' to just `''`. Or perhaps `'&nbsp;'` if it requires you to put something in there.

Answer (score 2):

You can also hide it via css, something like: `.comments_closed p { display: none; }`

Answer (score 1):

Try editing theme files and remove the php comments links, or add CSS to display:none to the comments div in your style sheet. But no one can help specifically unless you post some code.